# How can i share logic that is specific for two classes?

Tags: c++, architecture

I have next classes: WidgetBase, TextWidget, ObjectWidget, OtherWidget. TextWidget, OtherWidget and ObjectWidget inherits WidgetBase. ObjectWidget have some logic, that TextWidget should also have.

```c++
class WidgetBase
{
    // some base logic
}

class ObjectWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
}

class TextWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
}

class OtherWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // this class should not have logic that is specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
}
```

How can i share the logic that is specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget?
But also, TextWidget may not have this logic.  Decorators and recursive templates are not suitable here, unfortunately.

Comment: The same way you did it with the fully shared base logic? Create a `class ObjectTextWidgetBase : public WidgetBase` and let `ObjectWidget` and `TextWidget` derive from it? Is there some reason this doesn't work for you?

Comment: It is a test example, in a real life i have hierarchy of about 15 classes, and most of them should be able to have this logic, and do not have at the same time, so if i will use this approach, 15 classes will probably become 30 classes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way it to create a class with that common logic that inherits from `WidgetBase`. Then both `ObjectWidget` and `TextWidget` inherits from this class instead of directly inheriting from `WidgetBase`.

If you don't want `ObjectWidget` and `TextWidget` to have a common ancestor besides `WidgetBase`, then you can use the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) pattern. For that you create a template class with the common logic. Then `ObjectWidget` and `TextWidget` inherits from `WidgetBase`  and this template class (with the template parameter being the derived class).

Alternatively the template class can inherit from `WidgetBase` and then `ObjectWidget` and `TextWidget` only need to inherit from the template class.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple Inheritance should help you - Introduce an common util base(assuming the intermediate doenst need to have Basewidget props) for ObjWidget and TextWidget. Clarify, if this doesn't suit #

```
class WidgetBase
{
    // some base logic
}

class ObjTextCommonLogic 
{
    public:
    // Implement common logic method here
}
class ObjectWidget : public WidgetBase, protected ObjTextCommonLogic
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
}

class TextWidget : public WidgetBase, protected ObjTextCommonLogic
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
}

class OtherWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // this class should not have logic that is specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by `logic' in your query, but you can use Bridge Design Pattern as a solution like so:

```
struct impl {
    //implementations here
    void foo() { /* … */ }
    void bar() { /* … */ }
};

class ObjectWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
    public: void foo() { impl_->foo(); }    
    private: struct impl* impl_;
};

class TextWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // some logic specific for ObjectWidget and TextWidget
    public: void bar() { impl_->bar(); }
    private: struct impl* impl_;
};

class OtherWidget : public WidgetBase
{
    // no access to struct impl    
}
```